# Формирование значений матрицы на основе другой матрицы

Tags: python, python-3.x

Хочу написать "красивое" решение заполнение матрицы 1 или 0 на основе значений другой матрицы.

Входные данные:

```
matrix = [[2, 2, 2],
          [2, 4, 1],
          [2, 6, 0]]
topD = [3, 5, 2]
bottomD = [1, 3, 0]
```

Результирующая матрица строится таким образом:

Если элемент столбца больше соответствующих `bottomD` и меньше `topD` (`bottomD < elem < topD`), то в соответствующую ячейку записывается 1. В противном случае записывается 0.

Например, возьмем первый столбец:

```
1 < 2 < 3
1 < 2 < 3
1 < 2 < 3
```

Значит первый столбец результирующей матрицы будет:

```
[1,
 1,
 1]
```

Например, возьмем второй столбец:

```
3 < 2 < 5
3 < 4 < 5
3 < 6 < 5
```

Значит второй столбец результирующей матрицы будет:

```
[0,
 1,
 0]
```

Сейчас я имею вот такое решение, которое работает, но я хочу "решение в одну строку":

```
handyStructure = zip(zip(*imgAvg), zip(topD, bottomD))

for column, (big, low) in handyStructure:
    tmpRes = list()

    for elem in column:
        if low < elem < big: tmpRes.append(1)
        else: tmpRes.append(0)

    b.append(tmpRes)

b =  zip(*b)
```

`handyStructure` при таких входных данных имеет вид:

```
[((2, 2, 2), (3.0, 1.0)), ((2, 4, 6), (5.0, 3.0)), ((2, 1, 0), (2.0, 0.0))]
```

В попытках достич своего "идеала" дошел до вот этого:

```
res = [list(zip(column, (big, low))) for column, (big, low) in handyStructure]
```

С помощью этого я хотел достичь того, чтобы каждому элементу матрицы соответствовал нужная пара `topD` и `bottomD`. Но на этом этапе результат уже не верен. После того, как достич этого, я думал просто дописать что-то вроде:

```
1 if low < elem < big else 0
```

Пожалуйста, подскажите.

UPD:

Я достиг того, чего хотел. Вот код:

```
zip(*[[1 if low < element < big else 0 for element in column] for column, (big, low) in
      zip(zip(*imgAvg), zip(topD, bottomD))])
```

Но он слишком громоздкий. Может есть решение покороче?

Comment: Если любите однострочные решения то очень рекомендую начать изучать Numpy и Pandas - вам понравится ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Через списковое включение наверное будет понятнее (и короче), чем через `zip`:

```py
new_matrix = [[int(bottomD[i] < el < topD[i]) for i, el in enumerate(xs)] for xs in matrix]
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! Забыл про существование enumerate()

Answer (score 3):

Решение с использованием модуля Numpy:

```
import numpy as np   #  pip install numpy
```

сначала создадим Numpy матрицы из обычных матриц:

```
m = np.asarray(matrix)
top = np.asarray(topD)
bottom = np.asarray(bottomD)
```

решение:

```
res = (bottom < m) & (m < top)
```

результат:

```
In [12]: res
Out[12]:
array([[ True, False, False],
       [ True,  True,  True],
       [ True, False, False]])
```

или так:

```
In [13]: res.astype('int8')
Out[13]:
array([[1, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1],
       [1, 0, 0]], dtype=int8)
```

Comment: Прекрасное решение. Думаю, при активном использовании Numpy изменится и сам образ мышления

Comment: @СергейСиротенко, точно подмечено! Очень скоро вы начнете мыслить в категориях векторов и матриц вместо циклов и скаляров. ;)